# How to upgrade Samsung I5800 Galaxy 3 to Android 2.2?

Tags: samsung, updates

I have a Samsung I5800 Galaxy 3 with original Android firmware and an official Windows 7 Pro/64-bit machine and a Samsung USB cable that I got with the phone.

I read that Android 2.2 was already out for this phone from Jan-Apr this year, so I thought it would be a very wise thing to upgrade it! OK. Because it looks like Kies can't upgrade the phone, this is "funny".

Here is what I have on the phone:

[image]

> Android 2.1-update1

Here is the Kies version on the machine:

[image]

> 2.0.3.11082_152 (up-to-date)

Here is the message from Kies that it cannot update the phone:

> [image]

I tried to reboot the Windows 7 machine, Kies has a troubleshooting part, and I tried it.

**How can I update it officially to a fresher version of Android?** What else is there?

Answer (score 1):

You could uninstall Kies and the drivers completely, and then install the UK version of Kies from [here](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/detail/supportPrdDetail.do?menu=FW&prd_mdl_name=GT-I5800).  (Make sure to select the UK as your location during install).  This should allow you to perform the update, although it might not give you the language you want.  This worked for me to get Froyo on my Vibrant before it was released in the US.  Alternatively you could try another European country that has had an official update released.

You could also try flashing the latest European firmware via Odin.  [XDA has a guide on this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=778880) (see the UPGRADING section).  This is risky if you don't follow the instructions closely and will void your warranty just like rooting, but I've used Odin dozens of times on my Vibrant with no issues.